# changing the combobox cell background in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created the cell with combobox using DataGridViewComboBoxCell class in C#.But I want the combobox to look as as shown in image2.But using DataGridViewComboBoxCell the combo box appears as shown in image1.So how can we change form image1 to image2 in C#
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat you should use:

```
  var col = dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
 col.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```